# Variable not working

Tags: objective-c, string, variables, ios4

I want to set a variable value. But I don't know how to. I want replace 3456 with "value".

Code:

NSString *value = textbox.text;

NSString *field = [captcha stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('mainPagePart:rn3').value='3456';"];

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to say is you want to put the contents of `value` into the string?

```
NSString *field = [captcha stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('mainPagePart:rn3').value='%@';", value]];
```

Comment: No problem! You should mark this question as answered (green checkmark to the left).